# How do I host my webapp (made using HTML, CSS, JS, node and express) on GoDaddy hosting (cPanel)? I've already purchased a domain and hosting at it,

Tags: dns, hosting, web-hosting

I've already made a webapp using HTML, CSS, JS, node and express. Now I want to host it on GoDaddy. I've already purchased its domain and hosting. But the only option i'm observing frequently says WORDPRESS hosting (i'm assuming it says to build website on wordpress which I don't want to). I have the access to its cPanel but IDK how to use it (properly).

Answer (score 0):

In order to host your site, you just need to upload all your files via FTP to your root folder. From your explanation above, it should be basic website. You can just upload your files to your root folder. If you encounter issue, you can contact their support team.